# Laravel 5.5 : Testing with DatabaseMigrations deletes all tables

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.5

I've been teaching myself how to write test cases in Laravel 5.5.

I noticed that, when I run a test class which has `DatabaseMigrations` trait, all the DB tables relevant to the test class are deleted after running the test.

Does this happen by default? I haven't found any clue in the doc.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is `DatabaseTransactions` and `DatabaseMigrations`.

With `DatabaseTransactions` when  you run your test, it prepares the transactions, triggers the test and rolls everything back after execution

`DatabaseMigrations` triggers `php artisan migrate` command and before the application is destroyed, it rolls everything back.

There is also `RefreshDatabase` which came in Laravel 5.5, it kind of replaces `DatabaseMigrations` and `DatabaseTransactions`.

With `RefreshDatabase`, if you are using in-memory database, it will run `php artisan migrate` for you. If you are not using in-memory database, it will drop all your tables and do a fresh run of `php artisan migrate`.

I will suggest you to use an in-memory database, which can be defined as follow in the php tags of your `phpunit.xml` file.

```
...
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
</php>
```

Some of the advantages of the in-memory database are the following:

1. Runs really really fast
2. Does not affect your actual database because everything happen in the memory

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: It was great helping you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @PrinceLionelN'zi how does :memory: works. Does it will behave as MySql. (Support all the SQL)

Answer (score 1):

The `runDatabaseMigrations()` method in this trait executes `migrate:rollback` command after running tests. This command deletes all tables.

```
$this->artisan('migrate:rollback');
```